# Html 5 local storage in XUL application

Tags: html, local-storage, xul, xulrunner

I am trying to implement html5 local storage in a standalone xul application, I would like to use local-storage because I think the **Xpcom** way looks to complicated.

I have read that for a Firefox extension you can do:

```
document.content.localStorage.setItem("myvariable", "myvalue");
var item = document.content.localStorage.getItem("myvariable");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=item;
```

But this does not work for my standalone application, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround [here](http://fartersoft.com/blog/2011/03/07/using-localstorage-in-firefox-extensions-for-persistent-data-storage/).

```
var url = "http://example.com";
var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var ssm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptSecurityManager);
var dsm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/storagemanager;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMStorageManager);

var uri = ios.newURI(url, "", null);
var principal = ssm.getCodebasePrincipal(uri);
var storage = dsm.getLocalStorageForPrincipal(principal, "");

storage.setItem("chromekey", "chromevalue");
```

What it does is that it pretends  that it is example.com so Mozilla lets it assess loaclstorage.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var win = document.content.defaultView;
win.localStorage.setItem("myvariable", "myvalue");
var item = win.localStorage.getItem("myvariable"); // why not win.localStorage["myvariable"]
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=item;
```

localStorage is property of `window` object while you are trying to access it with `document` object

Note that this data would only be accessible from the documents of same domain where it was saved. So if `win.document` is from www.yahoo.com when you put a value in localStorage, `win.localStorage.getItem("myvariable")` will only return value for documents from www.yahoo.com/*

Comment: I am sorry, but I think that you have misunderstood. I am not making a web-page but a standalone application using Mozilla’s xulrunner. So this doesn’t work in my case.

Comment: ah ... Ok. I thought it was an extension